Do solvable groups and some conditions implies non-trivial center?
Does a finite group satisfying the following conditions have non-trivial center?

G is solvable,
$G=\langle x_1,\dots, x_n\rangle$,
All the $x_i$ belong to the same conjugacy class of $G$ (hence they have the same order, say $m$),
$\langle x_i \rangle \cap \langle x_j \rangle\neq 1$ for all $i,j$.

Remark: This is a follow-up of the question, where it is shown that the claim is false when $G$ is not solvable.
Approaches: I have verified the statement using brute-force computations and GAP's SmallGroups library for groups up to order 250. An inductive argument on the number of generators appears to be a promising approach.
Edit: Verified true up to order 400.
I would appreciate any comments or suggestions on how to proceed with the proof. Thanks in advance.

That you found no counterexample upto order $250$ is a good sign that the conditions are sufficient. Can we assume that $G$ is finite (since this is not explicitely mentioned in the question , but occurs in the tags ) ?

Thanks for your comment, Peter. The statement is somehow false when $G$ is not solvable: there is a significantly large counterexample ($ S_{11}$), and still, none exists up to order $250$. Nonetheless, we can assume that the group is finite. I apologize for not explicitly stating this earlier; I will correct it immediately.

Why can you not do something similar to the simple counterexample? Let $A,B,C$ be three soluble, centreless groups, generated by $a_1,a_2$, $b_1,b_2$ and $c_1,c_2$ respectively, with the $a_i$ conjugate in $A$, etc. Force the $a_i$, $b_i$ and $c_i$ to have coprime orders. say $2$, $3$ and $7$. (So, for example, $A\cong S_3$, $B\cong A_4$ and $C\cong (C_2^3)\rtimes 7$. Then $a_1b_1c_1$, $a_2b_1c_1$, $a_1b_2c_1$ and $a_1b_1c_2$ generate $G=A\times B\times C$. (This group has order 4032.)

The example I gave in the comments is a counterexample. The general construction is:
Let $A,B,C$ be three soluble, centreless groups, generated by a conjugacy class of elements $a_1,\dots,a_r$, $b_1,\dots,b_s$, $c_1,\dots,c_t$ of elements of orders $n_a$, $n_b$, $n_c$. Choose $A$, $B$ and $C$ so that $n_a,n_b$ and $n_c$ are mutually coprime.
Let $G=A\times B \times C$, generated by $a_ib_1c_1$, $a_1b_jc_1$ and $a_1b_1c_k$ for $1\leq i\leq r$, $1\leq j\leq s$, $1\leq k\leq t$. By construction all of these generators are conjugate, and clearly generate $G$. Also, $G$ is clearly soluble. Furthermore, each have at least one letter in common, so (since $n_a$, $n_b$ and $n_c$ are mutually coprime) the subgroups generated by any two generators intersect non-trivially.
Examples of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $S_3$ ($n_a=2$), $A_4$ ($n_b=3$), and $(2^3)\rtimes 7$, a Borel subgroup of $SL_2(8)$ of order $56$ ($n_c=7$). There are obviously infinitely many such examples.
For a supersoluble example you may choose $A$ as above, $B=C_7\rtimes C_3$ and $C=C_{11}\rtimes C_5$.
Edit: I think that in some sense this is a `minimal' counterexample. It is divisible by three primes and has four generators. You can get away with three generators by choosing $a_1b_1c_1$, $a_1b_2c_2$ and $a_2b_1c_2$. But three primes is necessary, as the following shows.
If $G$ is a $\{p,q\}$-group with the properties then it has a centre. To see this, notice that $\langle x_i\rangle\cap \langle x_j\rangle$ contains either a copy of $C_p$ or of $C_q$. Let $P$ and $Q$ denote the subgroups of orders $p$ and $q$ in $\langle x_1\rangle$ respectively.
Let $I$ denote the set of $i$ such that $P\leq \langle x_i\rangle$, and $J$ denote the set of $j$ such that $Q\leq \langle x_j\rangle$. Clearly $I\cup J=\{1,\dots,n\}$ (where $G$ is $n$-generator, as in the question). If $I=\{1,\dots,n\}$ then $P\leq Z(G)$, and similarly with $J$, so we let $j\notin I$ and $i\notin J$. What is $|\langle x_i\rangle \cap \langle x_j\rangle|$? It must be non-trivial, and so divisible by either $p$ or $q$. But then $j\in J$, so if it is divisible by $q$ then $Q\leq \langle x_i\rangle$, since $Q\leq \langle x_j\rangle$ and this intersection is cyclic. But $i\notin J$ by assumption, so the intersection cannot contain $Q$. Similarly it cannot contain $P$, and so we are done by contradiction.

Wonderful example!
